# Wordpress site not loading styles on desktop?

Tags: templates, performance

I've created a Wordpress website using Astra and Elementor. I haven't coded any of it or done anything manually other than using the editor to edit some template blocks.

Now, when I try to load one particular page from my site, it will load the headings and links but with none of the styling, including background images, button stylings, everything. It's just a white page with words and blue links.

Below is what the website is supposed to look like. And below that is what it's displaying as.

Additionally, it looks like if I let the broken website sit for a while and then refresh, the styling suddenly shows up. I am completely new to this and I have no idea what's happening, I have been google searching for hours and found millions of similar issues but no solutions that seem to work for this issue.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is associated with the browser cache. Try clearing it. It should fix your issue.

Also, you can try appending these PHP code to the **.css** file in the header for ruling out cache of the stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="your.css?<?php echo time(); ?>" />
```